# Issue installing BasicTeX with Cask under OS X

Tags: macos, homebrew

I followed the instructions (that I could understand) to install BasicTeX from Cask and this was the output I got:

```
basictex staged at '/opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom/basictex/latest' (107M)
```

I see this:

```
○ → ls -l /opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom/basictex/latest/
total 219936
-rw-r--r--  1 sunitjoshi  admin  112605547 Jan 13 07:28 BasicTeX.pkg
```

And this under ~/Applications; i.e. no BasicText.app

```
○ → ls ~/Applications/
Chrome Apps.localized emacs                 test.js
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR;** Add `/usr/local/texlive/2015basic/bin/universal-darwin` to your `PATH`.

There is no `BasicTeX.app`. BasicTex is now installed at `/usr/local/texlive/2015basic`, wether you use Brew Cask or not (you can also find something files at `/Library/Tex`, but that's just a bunch of symlinks pointing to the actual installation directory). Just add the above path to your `PATH` and you should be fine.

Further reference:

- [BasicTeX installation guide
  (non-Brew)](http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/BasicTeX.pdf). aaa
- https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163849/mavericks-upgrade-screwed-up-my-pdflatex-command-not-found
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22081991/rmarkdown-pandoc-pdflatex-not-found